# Failing to Authenticate with Jwt in .Net Core 2.1 with Angular front-end

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I am having trouble authenticating user info via Jwt tokens. I can successfully login and register new users, and once logged in, I can console.log the Jwt token from the front-end. But when I try to retrieve info from the back-end and the controller utilizes the [Authorize] attribute, I get the following logs:

> Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44325/api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=5
>
> Information: Route matched with {action = "GetAccounts", controller = "Accounts", page = ""}. Executing action MyApp.App.Controllers.AccountsController.GetAccounts (MyApp.App)
>
> Debug: Execution plan of authorization filters (in the following order): Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter
>
> Trace: Authorization Filter: Before executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.
>
> Information: Authorization failed.
>
> Trace: Authorization Filter: After executing OnAuthorizationAsync on filter Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter.
>
> Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
>
> Trace: Before executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.
>
> Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
>
> Information: AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
>
> Trace: After executing action result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.
>
> Information: Executed action MyApp.App.Controllers.AccountsController.GetAccounts (MyApp.App) in 62.8374ms
>
> Information: Request finished in 200.0118ms 401

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);
    ...
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
    ...
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    ...
}
```

**AccountsController.cs**

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LogUserActivity))]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBaseRepository _repo;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AccountsController(IBaseRepository repo, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAccounts([FromQuery] AccountParams accountParams)
    {
        var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

        accountParams.UserId = currentUserId;

        var accounts = await _repo.GetAccounts(accountParams);

        var accountsToReturn = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<AccountForListDto>>(accounts);

        Response.AddPagination(accounts.CurrentPage, accounts.PageSize, accounts.TotalCount, accounts.TotalPages);

        return Ok(accountsToReturn);
    }
}
```

**account-list.component.ts**

```
import ...

@Component({
  selector: "app-accounts",
  templateUrl: "./account-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./account-list.component.css"]
})
export class AccountListComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts: Account[];
  accountParams: any = {};
  pagination: Pagination;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private alertify: AlertifyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.accounts = data["accounts"].result;
      this.pagination = data["accounts"].pagination;
    });
  }

  loadAccounts() {
    this.accountService.getAccounts(this.pagination.currentPage, this.pagination.itemsPerPage, this.accountParams)
      .subscribe((res: PaginatedResult<Account[]>) => {
          this.accounts = res.result;
          this.pagination = res.pagination;
        },
        error => {
          this.alertify.error(error);
        });
  }
}
```

**account.service.ts**

```
import ...

@Injectable()
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  constructor(private authHttp: HttpClient) { }

  getAccounts(page?, itemsPerPage?, accountParams?: any) {
    const paginatedResult: PaginatedResult<Account[]> = new PaginatedResult<Account[]>();
    let params = new HttpParams();

    if (page != null && itemsPerPage != null) {
      params = params.append("pageNumber", page);
      params = params.append("pageSize", itemsPerPage);
    }

    return this.authHttp
      .get<Account[]>(this.baseUrl + "accounts", { observe: "response", params })
      .map(response => {
        paginatedResult.result = response.body;
        if (response.headers.get("Pagination") != null) {
          paginatedResult.pagination = JSON.parse(response.headers.get("Pagination"));
        }

        return paginatedResult;
      });
  }
```

**account-list.resolver.ts**

```
import ...

@Injectable()
export class AccountListResolver implements Resolve<Account[]> {
  pageSize = 5;
  pageNumber = 1;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService,
    private router: Router,
    private alertify: AlertifyService) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<Account[]> {
    return this.accountService.getAccounts(this.pageNumber, this.pageSize).catch(error => {
      this.alertify.error("Problem retrieving data");
      this.router.navigate(["/dashboard"]);
      return Observable.of(null);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be passing the token to the service in an Authorization header. You will need to do that when you do your Http get. See [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers).

Comment: You are correct. I was able to fix it by adding `httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': ``Bearer ${this.jwtHelperService.tokenGetter()}``
    })
  }`
 to account.service.ts and then passing that through the request headers.

Comment: Easy enough to forget when it is your first go around with Jwt.